# API stable way to automatically link to either MySQL or MariaDB in Debian for backward compatibility

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, mariadb, qmake

I upgraded from Debian Jessie to Debian Stretch, and now found out that MariaDB has replaced MySQL, which is fine.

Luckily, on C++, the MariaDB client is still accessible with

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

However, the linking is different. I used to link with `-lmysqlclient`, and now I have to link to `-lmariadbclient`.

My program has to work on both. So my question is: Is there a way to check whether MySQL is available, and if not, link to MariaDB?

I'm using **qmake** and **cmake** in the relevant projects. Please advise.

Comment: is it a real problem? Maria is highly compatible, or is exact replacement with mySQL

Comment: @JacekCz The problem is the linking. I need the make tool to automatically detect whether MariaDB or MySQL is available. I don't have a problem with MySQL or MariaDB as database handlers at all.

Comment: program linked in one environment suppose work well on the other ???

Comment: @JacekCz No. A makefile (qmake/cmake) is supposed to realize whether MySQL or MariaDB is available and make the right choice to do the linking based on what's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **cmake** you could simply use:

```
    find_library( MYSQL_LIBRARY
    NAMES "mysqlclient" "mysqlclient_r"
    PATHS "/lib/mysql"
          "/lib64/mysql"
          "/usr/lib/mysql"
          "/usr/lib64/mysql"
          "/usr/local/lib/mysql"
          "/usr/local/lib64/mysql"
          "/usr/mysql/lib/mysql"
          "/usr/mysql/lib64/mysql" )
```

And then check it with:

```
if(MYSQL_LIBRARY) {
  ...
}
```

Like the examples from github: [FindMYSQL(RenatoUtsch)](https://gist.github.com/RenatoUtsch/1623340) or [FindMySQL(mloskot)](https://github.com/mloskot/cmake-modules/blob/master/modules/FindMySQL.cmake).

---

For **qmake** the only thing i found is to check for typical locations like this:

```
!exists("/foo/bar/baz.so"):!exists("/hello/world/baz.so"):...: message("...")
```

Answer (score 0):

CMake module FindMariaDB is included with MariaDB. FindMySql seems to be external to MySql, there are lots of search results in GitHub repo's for it. Search for both, with the flag OPTIONAL. Then based on MariaDB_FOUND, set a variable to the value if MariaDB_LIBRARIES or MySql_LIBRARIES. Use that variable in subsequent target_link_libraries().

Comment: You're right. For CMake it shall not be a big issue. It didn't occur to me until just now. But for my current qmake projects I'm not sure how to deal with it.